# How to call a image class on a regular interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-plugins

I am having four classes inside each class a image is called

```
<div id="ban01" class="banner ban01">
</div>
<div id="ban02" class="banner ban02">
</div>
<div id="ban03" class="banner ban03">
</div>
<div id="ban04" class="banner ban04">
</div>
```

and my css class contains

```
.ban01 { background-image:url(../images/banner/01.jpg); }
.ban02 { background-image:url(../images/banner/02.jpg); }
.ban03 { background-image:url(../images/banner/03.jpg); }
.ban04 { background-image:url(../images/banner/04.jpg); }
```

and my Jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totDivs = $(".banner ban03").length;

    var currDiv = 0;
    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (currDiv > totDivs) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            return
        }
        $(".banner ban03").eq(currDiv).find('class').trigger("click");

        currDiv++;

    }, 2000);
});
```

how to call these classes in regular intervals sorry if i repeated the question again

Comment: What do you want do with this script?

Comment: Do you want to rotate this images?

Comment: @Maikay yes I want to rotate the images

Comment: First I notice that your css file is not referencing your ID correctly.  It should be #ban01 {...}.  use # to ref Id and . to ref Class.  Next it does not make sense to have a class name the same as the ID.  ID is a unique value for the entire document.  You need to clean up your css and you are incorrectly selecting.  It should simply be $(.banner) to get your list of banners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
<div id="ban01" class="banner ban01">
</div>
<div id="ban02" class="banner ban02">
</div>
<div id="ban03" class="banner ban03">
</div>
<div id="ban04" class="banner ban04">
</div>
```

style

```
.banner { height: 50px }
.ban01 { background: green }
.ban02 { background: blue }
.ban03 { background: red }
.ban04 { background: orange }
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totDivs = $(".banner").length;
    var currDiv = 0;
    var myInterval = setInterval(change, 2000);
    function change(){
        $(".banner").hide().eq(currDiv).show();
        currDiv = (currDiv + 1) % totDivs;
    }
    change();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b2Btj/1/

Answer (score 2):

> @Maikay yes I want to rotate the images

Why use JavaScript to rotate image ?

---

This is  possible with only [css](/questions/tagged/css). Use the property : [`animation`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

```css
.imageRotate {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

   -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear 1; // '1' for a single animation, if you need an infinite animation replace '1' by 'infinite'
   -moz-animation:spin 4s linear 1;
   animation:spin 4s linear 1;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin { 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
           transform:rotate(360deg); 
         } 
}
```

```html
<div id="ban01">
    <img class="imageRotate" src="http://socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you look on this answer... :-)

[jquery-timed-change-of-item-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263062/jquery-timed-change-of-item-class)

Try this while I'm doing your coding. :-D

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .a, .b, .c, .d, .e {
                height: 120px;
                width: 200px;
            }
            .a {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .b {
                background-color: green;
            }
            .c {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .d {
                background-color: black;
            }
            .e {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing</h1>

        <div id="test" class="a">How Are You Buddy?</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $( document ).ready(function() {
            var array = ['a','b','c','d','e'];//Here is your classes
            var len = array.length;
            var i=0;
            function changeDivClass(d) {
                $("#test").removeClass();
                $("#test").addClass(array[d]);
            }
            setInterval(function() {
                if(len>=i){
                    return changeDivClass(i++);
                }else{
                    i=0;
                    $("#test").removeClass();
                    $("#test").addClass('a');
                }
            }, 5000);
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i pasted this script in the fiddle but in a regular in a timed interval it is not moving from one class to another

Comment: @dennis No issue with the code. See my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/fYYMg/1/). I think you made a mistake while you post the code. Thanks. If this helpful to you. Please vote up.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what exactly the click trigger on the banner element will do, but maybe this helps:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var totDivs = $(".banner").length;
    var currDiv = 0;

    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {

        if (currDiv > totDivs) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            return;
        }

        $(".banner").eq(currDiv).trigger("click");

        currDiv++;

    }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: i dont think on trigger click image rotation will happen because here I am not clicking on the page to rotate image the images should automatically rotate

Answer (score -2):

what you could do is that you could run a for loop if you know the counts of the "div"

```
for(var count=0;count<3;count++)
{
var totDivs = $(".banner ban0"+count).length;

    var currDiv = 0;
    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (currDiv > totDivs) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            return
        }
        $(".banner ban0"+count).eq(currDiv).find('class').trigger("click");

        currDiv++;

    }, 2000);
}
```

May this could solve your issue .